# Collection Views in iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, uicollectionview

I was trying to build a weather app using swift 4 and openWeather API and i got stuck in this function:

```
func fetchWeather(){
    let weatherGetter = GetWeather()
    self.cityWeather = [Temperature]()
            for city in cities {
                    weatherGetter.getWeather(city: city) { (temp) in
                        guard let temp = temp else {return}
                        print(temp)
                        self.cityWeather?.append(temp)
                }
            }
    print(self.cityWeather?.count)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

So this function gives me this in the console

> Optional(0)
>   Temperature(city: "London", cityTemperature: "294.06", tempIcon: "01d")
>   Temperature(city: "Tokyo", cityTemperature: "297.33", tempIcon: "09n")
>   Temperature(city: "Paris", cityTemperature: "298.0", tempIcon: "01d")
>   Temperature(city: "Moscow", cityTemperature: "291.41", tempIcon: "01n")

And this looks really odd to me because the print(self.cityWeather?.count) is used after the for loop, but in the console Optional(0) comes first.

So if i use this method

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cityWeather?.count ?? 0
}
```

My collection view cells won't show up, because it's returning 0.

BUT if use print(self.cityWeather) after the self.cityWeather?.append(temp) i get this! (all other print statements i removed):

> Optional([WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Moscow", cityTemperature: "291.41", tempIcon: "01n")])
>   Optional([WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Moscow", cityTemperature: "291.41", tempIcon: "01n"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "London", cityTemperature: "294.05", tempIcon: "01d")])
>   Optional([WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Moscow", cityTemperature: "291.41", tempIcon: "01n"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "London", cityTemperature: "294.05", tempIcon: "01d"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Paris", cityTemperature: "298.0", tempIcon: "01d")])
>   Optional([WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Moscow", cityTemperature: "291.41", tempIcon: "01n"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "London", cityTemperature: "294.05", tempIcon: "01d"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Paris", cityTemperature: "298.0", tempIcon: "01d"), WhatsWeather.Temperature(city: "Tokyo", cityTemperature: "297.38", tempIcon: "09n")])

Comment: there was a flaw in the `count` logic, please check the updated answer.

Comment: @rakesha-shastri Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reload the `collectionView` only after all the cities data has been stored in your data source and since this is an API call, it will take time for each response to be received. So what you should be doing is check inside the completion if all the data has been received and then reload the `collectionView`.

```
func fetchWeather(){
    let weatherGetter = GetWeather()
    self.cityWeather = [Temperature]()
    var networkCallsDone = 0
    for city in cities {
        weatherGetter.getWeather(city: city) { (temp) in
            networkCallsDone += 1
            guard let temp = temp else {
                if networkCallsDone == cities.count {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        collectionView.reloadData()    //In case the last network call to finish does not return valid data
                    }        
                }
                return
            }
            print(temp)
            self.cityWeather?.append(temp)
            if networkCallsDone == cities.count {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     collectionView.reloadData()
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Thanks to matt for pointing out the error in logic while checking the `count` and the thread issue.

Comment: Your idea looks good, but the technique of looking at the `count` is wrong. The way to loop and not reload until the end is to use a DispatchGroup.

Comment: DispatchQueur.main.async {self.collectionView?.reloadData()} inside a for loop worked for me great except that the order of the cities got messed up somehow

Comment: _whoops_ i did not pay attention that it would be in a background thread because it is a network call. My bad. Thanks @matt. I understand the count thing. You mean i missed the count going down at `guard`. I'll fix that and update the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @matt i have updated the answer and i hope this is what you meant. If not, please feel free to edit the current answer or post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're appending `cityWeather` in `weatherGetter.getWeather` block, which is asynchronous operation and reloading `collectionView` synchronously (before data gets back from server).

Try this:

```
func fetchWeather(){
    let weatherGetter = GetWeather()
    self.cityWeather = [Temperature]()
    for city in cities {
        weatherGetter.getWeather(city: city) { (temp) in
            guard let temp = temp else {return}
            self.cityWeather?.append(temp)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reloading the `collectionView` everytime a city data is received, which i don't think is what the OP wants or anyone wants for that matter. You would only want to do that once after all the data has been received.